# Issue with comparing input to dates from .txt file

Tags: java, file, date, for-loop, arraylist

I'm writing a program that interacts with a "Transactions.txt" file that's formatted as follows.

```
TransactionNumber,ItemName,Quantity,Purchase/HireDate,ReturnDate
```

which has the contents:

```
T01,Jumper,5,10/03/2015,14/03/2015
T02,Tuxedo,1,21/04/2015,23/05/2015
T03,Jacket,2,02/07/2015,09/07/2015
T04,Hat,3,12/09/2015,19/09/2015
T05,Shoes,4,09/11/2015,20/11/2015
```

The program's goal is to get in a start date and to check through all the dates in the file to see if the start date is before any of the dates and if it is it will add the Item Name, it's Quantity and it's Purchase/Hire date and it's Return date to a String to be printed. For example if I enter 10/03/2015 as the start date, all the contents should be printed but only lines 1, 2 and 4 are being printed out and I have no idea where the issue is arising.

I'm also trying to add on a piece of code that will get in the end date and will check if any of the dates in the file is after the end date and if it is, the output will be printed and then it should finish executing main (not exit(0) as I have it interacting with other classes. So if I would then enter 10/03/2015 as the start date and 15/03/2015 as the end date, only line 1's contents would be printed.

I've been trying to fix this issue for a few hours now and I can't find where it is going wrong, any help would be very appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public static File transactionsFile = new File("Transactions.txt");
public class Transaction
{
    public static void main() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            String details = "";
            Date tempDate;
            SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            System.out.print("Enter in a start date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            String sDate = userInput.nextLine();
            Date startDate = SDF.parse(sDate);
            System.out.print("Enter in an end date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            String eDate = userInput.nextLine();
            Date endDate = SDF.parse(eDate);
            List<String[]> contents = new ArrayList<>();
            Scanner searchTransactionsFile = new Scanner(transactionsFile);
            System.out.println("\n---------Summary of Transactions---------");

            while(searchTransactionsFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] current = searchTransactionsFile.nextLine().split(",");
                contents.add(current);
            }

            for(String[] elements: contents)
            {
                tempDate = SDF.parse(elements[3]);
                if(tempDate.after(startDate) || tempDate.equals(startDate))
                    details += "\nItem Name:\t\t" + elements[1] + "\nQuantity:\t\t" + elements[2] + "\nHire/Purchase Date:\t" + elements[3] + "\nReturn Date:\t\t" + elements[4] + "\n";
            }
            System.out.print(details);
            searchTransactionsFile.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid date entered. Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: When I enter 10/03/2015 as the start date, ignoring the end date and just enter any random date, all 5 lines from the file should be printed but only 3/5 are being printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line

```
public static File transactionsFile = new File("Transactions.txt");
```

inside class definition.
And you must define the `userInput` variable. like this

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Also you have to modify the format of Date to be:

```
SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Because `mm` for minutes and `M` for month;

Comment: Those two lines made the code block compilable. But actual issue is with if logic.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about those errors, I have the code above as a method of a class that has the scanner and files declared globally in a different class, I just forgot to place them correctly when putting it into a single class to post up on here.

Comment: now, what is the problem with the second answer of ravindra ?

Comment: When I enter 09/03/2015 as the start Date then 21/11/2015 as the end date, all the dates in the file are inside those constraints which means that all 5 items should be printed out, but only 4 do, Jacket does not get printed out.

Comment: That fixed it thanks alot, I forgot that M needed to be capitalized, would MM do the same job as M?

Comment: Welcome, I am not sure about `MM` but I test it and it work like `M`

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is wrong. It is not considering the end date. I have changed the logic to consider both startDate and endDate. Have a look at it.

***if (tempDate.after(startDate) && tempDate.before(endDate))***

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Transaction {
    public static File transactionsFile = new File("Transactions.txt");

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        try {

            String details = "";
            Date tempDate;
            SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            System.out.print("Enter in a start date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String sDate = userInput.nextLine();
            Date startDate = SDF.parse(sDate);
            System.out.print("Enter in an end date (dd/mm/yyyy): ");
            String eDate = userInput.nextLine();
            Date endDate = SDF.parse(eDate);
            List<String[]> contents = new ArrayList<>();
            Scanner searchTransactionsFile = new Scanner(transactionsFile);
            System.out.println("\n---------Summary of Transactions---------");

            while (searchTransactionsFile.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] current = searchTransactionsFile.nextLine().split(",");
                contents.add(current);
            }

            for (String[] elements : contents) {
                tempDate = SDF.parse(elements[3]);
                if (tempDate.after(startDate) && tempDate.before(endDate))
                    details += "\nItem Name:\t\t" + elements[1]
                            + "\nQuantity:\t\t" + elements[2]
                            + "\nHire/Purchase Date:\t" + elements[3]
                            + "\nReturn Date:\t\t" + elements[4] + "\n";
            }
            System.out.print(details);
            searchTransactionsFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Invalid date entered. Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
D:\Study\Examples\src>java Transaction
Enter in a start date (dd/mm/yyyy): 10/03/2015
Enter in an end date (dd/mm/yyyy): 15/03/2015

---------Summary of Transactions---------

Item Name:              Hat
Quantity:               3
Hire/Purchase Date:     12/09/2015
Return Date:            19/09/2015
```

Comment: I finally see what went wrong, thanks! Although when I enter say, 09/03/2015 as the start Date then 21/11/2015 as the end date, Jacket from the file doesn't get printed, even though it's within those constraints. All 5 items should be printed, but only 4 did.